# Problem in Declaration and using SqlParameter[].ERROR:Use of unassigned local variable 'sqlparam'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have to Declare a SqlParameter[].
It's size is dynamic based on the dropdownlist selection. 
I have implemented a method as below

```
protected void BindGrid()
{
    SqlParameter[] sqlparam;
    string SP = string.Empty;

    if (ddlKPIType.SelectedIndex == 0)//For Overall
    {
        sqlparam = PrepareSqlParams();

    }
    else if (ddlKPIType.SelectedIndex == 1)//For Parameterwise
    {
        sqlparam = PrepareSqlParamsForParameterWise();

    }
    else if (ddlKPIType.SelectedIndex == 2)//For Measurement Criteria wise
    {
        sqlparam = PrepareSqlParamsForMeasurmentCriteriaWise();

    }


    DataSet dsReport = GetReportDataSet(sqlparam, SP);

    if (isDataSetValid(dsReport))
        gridMonthlyReport.DataSource = dsReport.Tables[0];
    gridMonthlyReport.DataBind();

}
```

But in this code when I pass the sqlparam as a Parameter to GetReportDataSet() it is showing the error"Use of unassigned local variable 'sqlparam'.

The methods :`PrepareSqlParams()
,
PrepareSqlParamsForParameterWise() and
PrepareSqlParamsForMeasurmentCriteriaWise()` will return SqlParameter[].

Where I am making a mistake?
Any one please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all celles of sqlparam nun null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlparam` is not guaranteed to be assigned, because there is no `else` clause. If `ddlKPIType.SelectedIndex` is 3 or greater, `sqlparam` will not be assigned, because none of the branches of your `if-else if` clause will be executed.
You can overcome this in several ways:

1. If you are sure, that it can never be 3 or greater, insert an `else` clause that throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
2. If you are not sure that it can never be 3 or greater, just initialize `sqlparam`.